# React and TypeScript: incorrectly extends base class 'Component'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a class with TypeScript that extends `React.Component`, but I'm having this error:

```
Class 'Provider' incorrectly extends base class 'Component<{}, {}>'.
Types of property 'render' are incompatible. 
Type '(props: any) => any' is not assignable to type '() => false | Element'.
```

Here's the code:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class Provider extends React.Component {
  props;
  getChildContext() {
    const { children, ...context } = this.props;
    return context;
  }
  render(props) {
    const { children } = props;
    return children[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `render()` doesn't expect an argument. I suspect you are supposed to be using `this.props`?

Also your definition of an attribute `props` of type `any` is going to hide the type of `props` attribute in the base class so the compiler won't be able to work out the type of `children[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the props when extending React.Component.

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html):

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }
    // 'HelloProps' describes the shape of props.
    // State is never set so we use the 'undefined' type.
export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, undefined> {
        render() {
            return <h1>Hello from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>;
        }
    }
```

In addition to this: render doesn't accept an argument. 
`render()`
is correct.